# Get limit in a module controller

Tags: controllers

I'm newbie with Magento and I need something that probably it's very stupid. In a custom module I've got a controller and in that controller I want to read a variable. This variable is the products per page number. Does anybody know which helper or what else I need to read that?

The variable I want to read is a variable configurable in Magento administrator in Configuration/Catalog:
-Products per Page on Grid Default Value

Thank you!

Comment: Please update your question with more details like which data you need and what are you going to do with that data?

Comment: I already writted that I want the products per page variable, that is configurable in Magento administrator, in the Catalog section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is:

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
```

You may access any configuration node this way, just putting correct XML path (which you may look up in desired module's `system.xml` files).

Answer (score 1):

Products per page on grid allowed values:

```
$allowedValues = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page_values');
```

Products per page on grid default value

```
$defaultValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/grid_per_page');
```

Hope this helps..